# Error;Can't update table 'score' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, xampp, database-trigger

[This how i Created My triiger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaN1B.png)

please tell me how resolve this

Can't update table 'score' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: You can paste your query directly into the question, no need to add a screen for that :)

Comment: Since i created trigger using the WAMP i can't get complete query so added screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the NEW directly to modify the data:

```
CREATE TRIGGER rem BEFORE INSERT ON score
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

set NEW.remark = if(NEW.score = 0, 'bad', 'good');

END;
```

And yes, it's better to post the actual code rather than an image.

Comment: Since i created trigger using the WAMP i can't get complete query so added screenshot